# Bootstrap 3 RadioButtons to buttons not working entirely correctly under ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Details:

- ASP.NET 4.5.1
- MVC 5
- Entity Framework 6 extended by BrockAllen Identity Reboot 2
- Bootstrap 3.3.6 via NuGet

I am looking at the [CheckBox and Radio Buttons functionality](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons). I understand the `div` with the `label` inside of it. I understand that both `input` and associated text needs to be inside the `label`.

When I put the `input` outside the `label` and add the `for=` attribute to the label, the radio buttons appear outside of the Bootstrap buttons and clicking on a bootstrap button switches the selection to the correct radio button to the correct Bootstrap button. As such, so far so good; the bootstrap buttons appear to be correctly affecting the underlying radio buttons.

However, what is *NOT* happening is that the Bootstrap buttons themselves change to display this change in state. As in, if I click on the normally-non-selected button, the `active` class does not switch away from the selected button and end up on the unselected button as per the linked example above.

Since my MVC code is somewhat hairy (and not relevant to the performance of the Bootstrap item itself), I will leave it out for now and concentrate on what the MVC code outputs to the browser (since that *is* important).

Below is my generated output:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement2">
    <input id="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement2" type="radio" value="e1c8c5ba-e7ce-e511-8265-14feb5fbeae8" name="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement" autocomplete="off">
    Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" for="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement1">
    <input id="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement1" type="radio" value="1876ce88-e7ce-e511-8265-14feb5fbeae8" name="G1Q1_DirectedToImplement" checked="" autocomplete="off">
    No
  </label>
</div>
```

The strange thing is, when I plug this HTML into something like [this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0nevkwyn/), it works. Which makes me suspect that while the generated HTML (`div`, `label` & `input`) is correct, I have failed to set something up correct elsewhere. My page headers are as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/accordion.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/dialog.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/draggable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/progressbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/selectable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/selectmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/slider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/sortable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/spinner.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/tabs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/tooltip.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Themes/Base/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/site.css">
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js">
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js">
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.generics.js">
```

With the last script file entry being a catch-all for manually created jQuery custom code (such as pop-up calendars for Firefox). Bootstrap has been linked to correctly, as I am able to expand the script entry from within the HTML source under Firebug, which shows its contents have been successfully downloaded by the browser.

I was under the impression that all I had to do was decorate the HTML with the correct classes and secondary attributes, and I could pull in specific Bootstrap functionality at will without having to trigger it elsewhere via JavaScript handlers. Am I correct in that impression? Or did I simply fail to set things up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, FFS. Here I am, thinking it’s 2016, when it is really 1966 and BASIC rules still dominate the code: turns out that **the order in which you have your JS files loaded matters!!**

I mean, to hell with object-oriented programming, where an object can sit anywhere in the code and still be referenced as long as it remains within the same namespace and inheritance scope; here we need to have an item appear on line 50 if it is to be successfully referenced on line 60 and later. This brings me right back to my BASIC days, sure enough.

**Pro tip:** Load jQuery *before* Bootstrap, *à la* 1960s BASIC, or the entire edifice collapses. I mean, it makes sense with CSS because… well… it *cascades*, and therefore anything appearing later supersedes that which came before. But JavaScript? Isn’t its claim to fame being its *object oriented* nature, which *by fundamental definition of being object oriented* means that it is *independent* of position or location, so long as it is within scope??

Holy Mary, mother of God, I’m practically having an aneurysm here trying to understand how something that is *supposed* to be object-oriented is so dependent on its line-position within the code or calling order.